# Content delivery using Java and Plone CMS

Tags: jakarta-ee, content-management-system, seam, plone

I have a website developed using Java EE and the Seam Framework. We are currently investigating the possibilities to add a CMS in the project.

Reading this [article](http://www.gerrykirk.net/10-reasons-to-choose-plone-cms-for-your-web-site/) I got the impression that [Plone](http://plone.org/) is able to deliver content using Java, but I was not able to find any documentation or case studies yet.

Does anyone here have experience with this match? Possibly with the Seam framework in the mix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to use a Plone add-on called Content Mirror to export Plone content to a relational database for use from another system.

For an example of using Content Mirror to integrate Plone with Django, see http://plone.org/documentation/kb/send-plone-content-to-a-django-web-app-via-contentmirror

I'm not aware of similar tutorials for integrating with a Java-based system, but presumably the hard part is getting the data into the relational db, which should work the same.

Answer (score 1):

Content Mirror is probably the way to go for your usecase.

There is a case-study listed here that might help you figure out if this is right for your case or not: 
http://plone.org/support/case-studies/airports-site-evolves-grows-with-decoupled-delivery

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XML-RPC](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/plone-community-developer-documentation/serving/xmlrpc) to get content out of Plone.

Answer (score 0):

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/wsapi4plone.core

provides an easy to use webservice-like API